# Подскажите как исправить ошибку: "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, async-await

подскажите где ошибка , ошибка всплывает только тогда когда больше 1 подписчика на канале.

код ошибки

```
    ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
    future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<scheduled() done, defined at bot.py:35> exception=ValueError('I/O operation on closed file')>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "bot.py", line 56, in scheduled
        await bot.send_photo(
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 289, in send_photo
        result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_PHOTO, payload, files)
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 201, in request
        return await api.make_request(self.session, self.__token, method, data, files,
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 103, in make_request
        async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
        self._resp = await self._coro
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 464, in _request
        req = self._request_class(
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 293, in __init__
        self.update_body_from_data(data)
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 478, in update_body_from_data
        body = body()
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\formdata.py", line 148, in __call__
        return self._gen_form_data()
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\formdata.py", line 142, in _gen_form_data
        self._writer.append_payload(part)
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\multipart.py", line 826, in append_payload
        size = payload.size
      File "D:\telegabot\env\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\payload.py", line 371, in size
        return os.fstat(self._value.fileno()).st_size - self._value.tell()
    ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

код бота

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram import Bot,Dispatcher,executor,types
from sqliter import SQLiter
from pars import StopGame
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot=Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp=Dispatcher(bot)

db = SQLiter('db.db')
sg=StopGame('lastkey.txt')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
    
    await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на Новинки!")

@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы и так не подписаны.")
    else:
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)

        await message.answer("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")

async def scheduled(wait_for):

    while True:

        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)

        # проверяем наличие новых игр
        new_games = sg.new_games()

        if(new_games):
            # если игры есть, переворачиваем список и итерируем
            # new_games.reverse()
            for ng in new_games:
                nfo = sg.game_info(ng)

                # получаем список подписчиков бота
                subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()

                # отправляем всем новость
                with open(sg.download_image(nfo['image']), 'rb') as photo:
                    for s in subscriptions:
                        await bot.send_photo(
                            s[1],
                            photo,
                            caption = nfo['title'] + "\n"  + nfo['excerpt'] + "\n" + nfo['price'] + "\n\n" + nfo['link'],
                            disable_notification = True
                        )
                
                # обновляем ключ
                sg.update_lastkey(nfo['id'])

# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(scheduled(10)) # пока что оставим 10 секунд (в качестве теста)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

код парсинга

```
    import re
import os.path
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class StopGame:
    host = 'https://parfumelover.herokuapp.com'
    url = 'https://parfumelover.herokuapp.com'
    lastkey = ""
    lastkey_file = ""

    def __init__(self, lastkey_file):
        self.lastkey_file = lastkey_file

        if(os.path.exists(lastkey_file)):
            self.lastkey = open(lastkey_file, 'r').read()
        else:
            f = open(lastkey_file, 'w')
            self.lastkey = self.get_lastkey()
            f.write(self.lastkey)
            f.close()

    def new_games(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

        new = []
        items = html.select('.info-wrap > .fix-height >  a')
        for i in items:
            key = int((i['href'].replace('/show?id=','')))
            if(int(self.lastkey) < int(key)):
                new.append(i['href'])

        return new

    def game_info(self, uri):
        link = self.host + uri
        r = requests.get(link)
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

        # poster =html.select('.img-wrap > .img-fluid')[1]['src']
        
        poster=html.select('.img-fluid')[0]['src']
        info = {
            "id": uri.replace('/show?id=',''),
            "title": html.select('.p-4')[0].text.split('\n')[1],
            "link": link,
            "image": poster,
            # 'https://parfumelover.herokuapp.com/',+poster,
            "excerpt":html.select('.p-4')[0].text.split('\n')[2],
            "price":html.select('.display-4')[0].text
        };

        return info

    def download_image(self, url):
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

        a = urlparse(url)
        filename = os.path.basename(a.path)
        open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)

        return filename

# 103218

    def get_lastkey(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

        items = html.select('.info-wrap > .fix-height >  a')
        return items[0]['href'].replace('/show?id=','')

    def parse_href(self, href):
        result = href['href'].replace('/show?id=','')
        return result

    def update_lastkey(self, new_key):
        self.lastkey = int(new_key)

        with open(self.lastkey_file, "r+") as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.write(str(new_key))
            f.truncate()

        return new_key
```

заранее благодарен

Comment: Вопрос закрыт Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобная ошибка уже была рассмотрена в: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/issues/227

Суть в том, что переданный файл в `send_photo` будет считан, а это сдвинет его внутренную позицию в конец, из-за чего и будет ошибка при повторной попытке обращения к нем.

Можно попробовать вручную сдвигать позицию в начало файла через `.seek(0)`.

Пример:

```
...
            # отправляем всем новость
            with open(sg.download_image(nfo['image']), 'rb') as photo:
                for s in subscriptions:
                    await bot.send_photo(
                        s[1],
                        photo,
                        caption = nfo['title'] + "\n"  + nfo['excerpt'] + "\n" + nfo['price'] + "\n\n" + nfo['link'],
                        disable_notification = True
                    )
                    photo.seek(0)
...
```

Или открывать файл для каждого подписчика:

```
...
            # отправляем всем новость
            for s in subscriptions:
                with open(sg.download_image(nfo['image']), 'rb') as photo:
                    await bot.send_photo(
                        s[1],
                        photo,
                        caption = nfo['title'] + "\n"  + nfo['excerpt'] + "\n" + nfo['price'] + "\n\n" + nfo['link'],
                        disable_notification = True
                    )
...
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению не помогло exception=ValueError('I/O operation on closed file')

Comment: @Kirill, странно, не должно было быть. Бот перезагружен? В трассе ошибки на строку с `await bot.send_photo` указывается? Можно попробовать `photo.seek(0)` перед `await bot.send_photo` поместить, но это вряд ли поможет. Другой вариант -- открытие файла для каждого подписчика, обновлю ответ

Comment: ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<scheduled() done, defined at bot.py:35> exception=ValueError('seek of closed file')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 64, in scheduled
    photo.seek(0)
ValueError: seek of closed file

Comment: С открытием файла помогло, огромное спасибо!

Comment: теперь выскакивает новая ошибка не подскажите  как исправить ? ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<scheduled() done, defined at bot.py:35> exception=ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)))>

Comment: @Kirill, не думаю, что эта ошибка связана с текущей темой, но судя по тексту ошибки `Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение` какая-то проблема с подключением к серверу. Не знаю с каким проблема, но скорее всего это https://parfumelover.herokuapp.com . Такое бывает, можно запрос отправки (`request.get`) обернуть в бесконечный цикл и выходить из него, если отправка прошла успешно, [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8b1987030efdcc2e144eaf418049a87bbc50321a/html_parsing/get_game_genres/genre_translate_file/utils.py#L34)